# How can I patch a variable/function that is not defined - unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, databricks

I'm currently writing some databricks code which can "magically" import from other files, however, when testing locally using regular python, the functions/variables that would be imported are not there.

I have abstracted the code to just the core problem, without databricks stuff.

How can I patch a function that has not been defined in the file, nor has an import.

**demo.py**

```
def saySomething():
    return sayHello()

saySomething() # test works without this line

# continue with further code execution
# ...
```

**test_demo.py**

```
from unittest.mock import patch
import demo

def test_fs():
    with patch.object(demo, 'sayHello', return_value="hello", create=True):
        assert demo.saySomething() == "hello"
```

Whenever I run any tests, the code is failing as the import is before the test begins, thus evaluating the file straight away and can see that sayHello function is not defined.

> NameError: name 'sayHello' is not defined

Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

We don't direct approach . But as workaround ,to get the result back as a DataFrame from different notebook in Databricks we can do as below.

**notebook1**

def func1(arg):

```
df=df.transfomationlogic
return df
```

**notebook2**

%run path-of-notebook1

```
df=func1(**dfinput**)
Here the dfinput is a df you are passing and you will get the transformed df back from func1.
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. I'm importing utility functions from the 2nd notebook

Comment: please check it here . https://databricks.com/blog/2021/10/07/databricks-repos-is-now-generally-available.html this is new features with databricks